# iOS 9.1 BLE Connects and Immediately Disconnects

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios9.1

When I connect to a BLE peripheral using encryption on iOS 9.1 using a iPhone 6S the BLE peripheral is immediately disconnected. I've verified that this works on iOS 8 and 9.02. I've validated that the CBCentralManager didConnect delegate method is being called and a valid CBPeripheral object is being returned.

The BLE peripheral is disconnected immediately. I'm not able to even proceed to discover any services or characteristics before it is disconnected. The CBCentralManager didDisconnect method is called, but no error is returned.

Is anyone else seeing this? This has been working correctly for over a year and like I said it's only happening when using iOS 9.1 on the iPhone 6S. Don't have any other peripherals on 9.1 to test with.

**UPDATE**

According to Apple the issue is happening because we're not bonding the peripheral with the iPhone. So we've updated the firmware on the peripheral and are now bonding. This is presenting different issues surrounding maintaining bonding pairs between the phone and the peripheral. Our peripheral has a limited amount of memory, so we cannot maintain an infinite amount of bond references. To handle this scenario the peripheral allows for a maximum of 8 BLE bonds to be stored. When it receives a ninth request the first bond is removed from the peripherals list of bonded devices. This presents an issue because the iPhone doesn't know this bond has been removed and when I try to connect with the first device and interact with a characteristic I'm not prompted to pair. Which from my understanding is what kicks off the encryption process.

I'm wondering if there is anyway to remove a bond / device from an iPhones list of bonded devices, other then going into the Bluetooth settings and 'Forgetting' the device.

**UPDATE #2**

Apple has confirmed that there is NOT a way to remove a bonded peripheral from the 'MY Devices' section within the Bluetooth settings in the application due to security issues.

Based on this the scenario has now turned into the following. The iOS device has a reference to what was once a bonded peripheral under "My Devices" however that peripheral no longer has a reference to the iOS device within it's bonded devices table.

When I attempt to connect the iOS device, which still has the bond reference in it, to the peripheral that no longer has the bond reference we can connect successfully. However, after I connect successfully I discover the characteristic, set it to notify and receive no response and no pairing message. The only solution that fixes this issue is going into 'Settings' and 'Forgetting' the device and then attempting to reconnect.

Has anyone else experience this issue? Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I've received a response from Apple's technical support stating that this has something to do with the fact that iOS 9 is now using the new LE Secure Connections pairing model. They believe the root reason for the issue is the peripherals assuming that some reserved bits in BLE Spec 4.0 would always be zero.iOS 9 is now using the new LE Secure Connections pairing model, and the SC bit is set to 1 in the pairing request. Will post more as I find out.

Comment: Silly question but did you retain a copy of the CBPeripheral before trying to connect? From Apple's doc: "You must retain a local copy of the peripheral if any command is to be performed on it."

Comment: Yep. This has been working correctly for over a year. It's specifically iOS 9.1 that has this problem. I'll take a look at the docs again in any case.

Comment: Hi. We have also had similar problems since 9.1. @JamesParker iOS 9.1 still uses Bluetooth 4.1 so no support for LE Secure Connections. Do you have the possibility to use a BLE sniffer to see what's going on in the air (for example this one https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF-Sniffer)?

Comment: have you found any solution for this.

Comment: No. As of right now we have removed encryption entirely. This is actually what Apple suggested.

Comment: my problem is little different, we are not using any encryption. When we connect to a device it gets disconnected right after, but there is button on the peripheral when we press it device gets reseted and then it connects properly and perform all the operations. Can you suggest , like what i am doing wrong and what can i do to remove this issue.

Comment: I would post your own question, since that is a completely different scenario. It also sounds like a firmware issue not an iOS issue.

Comment: yeah, yesterday i went through the apple developer documentation and found what you said earlier that apple have adopted LE secure connections pairing model and it is something about SC bit. Can you please provide me some details on this.